# Error 404 with subdomain in ssl

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

Hello i  got an Error 404 with subdomain in ssl
when i run panel.terahost.org in https
i get a blank page https://panel.terahost.org
i found the error in 
error is

''This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources''

its trying to show unsafe script which is uploaded up there on secured page

note the panel is in orginal its uploaded here 
46.166.168.175/Tera-Host/index.php 
but i use this script to show it up
https://www.mediafire.com/?87syl3od21qdemy

Answer (score 0):

You should have wildcard ssl for subdomains to work. If you have wildcard then also it is showing that error then please check your html rendering. You should have https in front of all your urls on page. If your html have any link of http then it will show this error. I can see that you have frame of page with url `http://46.166.168.175/Tera-Host/index.php` change it to https.

Comment: http://46.166.168.175/Tera-Host/index.php its just an vps working with apache cant do anythin with it

Comment: Then it is not possible. Because it is necessary for https to have all resources to be encrypted otherwise there is no need of https. So use http  for `https://panel.terahost.org` or buy a domain host it on your vps and add a ssl certificate.